# No class def error found in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and in my app I have imported a library from github and I have included in my project but when I run app I am getting "No class def found error".
Link of github is "https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/tree/master/simple-crop-image-lib". Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that I can't see any Activities in your [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/blob/master/simple-crop-image-lib/AndroidManifest.xml).

If you're just starting out in Android might I suggest getting the free [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from Google. It will generate a new working project for you to get you started.

If you're already using Android Studio, ensure that you're using the shortcuts to [add a new Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). There's plenty of good training guides under that last link to help you get started.